# ggplot2: stacked barplot over different columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following sample data with three different cost-types and a year-column:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
costsA <- sample(100:200,30, replace=T)
costsB <- sample(100:140,30, replace=T)
costsC <- sample(20:20,30, replace=T)
year <- sample(c("2000", "2010", "2030"), 30, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(costsA, costsB, costsC, year)
```

My goal is to plot these costs in a stacked barplot, so that I can compare the mean-costs between the three year-categories. In order to do so I aggregated the values:

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            meanA = mean(costsA),
            meanB = mean(costsB),
            meanC = mean(costsC)) %>%
ggplot( ... ) + geom_bar()
```

But how can I plot the graph now? In the x-axis there should be the years and in the y-axis the stacked costs.

[image: example]

Comment: What you want to do is not quite clear to me but something like this?? `df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            meanA = mean(costsA),
            meanB = mean(costsB),
            meanC = mean(costsC)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", - c(year, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = key, fill = key)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the summarise data into a tidy(-ish) format to generate a plot like the one you posted. In a tidy-verse, you'd do that with `gather` function where you convert multiple columns into two-columns of key-value pairs. For instance, the following code generates the figure below.

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),
            meanA = mean(costsA),
            meanB = mean(costsB),
            meanC = mean(costsC)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", - c(year, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, group = key, fill = key)) + geom_col()
```

With `gather("key", "value", - c(year, n))`, three columns (costsA, costsB, costsC) are changed to the key-value pairs.

[image]

Comment: You may want to use `geom_col` here, `geom_bar` is proportional to the number of cases while `geom_col` is proportional to the values.  The original question had $ as the y axis and not count.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. I believe that `geom_col()` is identical to `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')` but I tend to forget `geom_col()` exists.